# How does download-them-all plugin works?

Tags: https, download, firefox-addon, mozilla

I was using [download-them-all](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) plugin in mozilla to download videos on a page in one go. It is very good at what it do.

But i could not understand how it do it over https websites ?

I first thought that it would be parsing the webpage html content and then hitting those urls.

I tried to do it in a separate python application with the url, but could not do it. That should be the issue of session cookies and all other things.

Is it possible only through a plugin ? 
Can it be done with a web-application like a website where users give us the url and we can act on that ?